# “Il est”: what does it mean?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, genre

I have been studying French for a few months now.

I am currently studying *quelle* and *quel* and I have a question that I don't understand the answer of. So, the question is:

> *De quelle couleur est votre manteau?*

The answer is:

> The coat is beige.

So, I wrote:

> *Mon manteau a beige couleur.*

But the answer was:

> *Il est beige.*

From what I understood, *il est* means *he is*. So why does it mean *it is*?

I am not clear on why *il est* changes its meaning to *it is*. I would very much appreciate it if you provided me with some clarification as to how the meaning is changed. Basic grammar is what I need!

Comment: @SeoncheolPark Welcome to French Language Stack Exchange! You're invited to take the **[tour](https://french.stackexchange.com/tour)** and visit the **[Help Centre](https://french.stackexchange.com/help)**, and continue to ask more questions as you learn French. :)

Comment: There is no equivalent for "it" in French. Objects are gendered and "manteau" happens to be "male". Therefore "il est beige". Your answer could have been correct save for a few errors: "mon manteau est de couleur beige" although this would almost never be used when speaking.

Comment: did you try to search for the translation of "it" in French?

Comment: A much more interesting question would have been why the answer to the the question as given was not simply, "Beige".

Comment: @MrLister This would not be a question for French Language and it would probably be put on hold since it would have no relation to the French Language, it is an issue in language teaching. The answer is because language teachers don't always teach real language but their student say things that natives do not often say in real life. The question  might be fit for [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/) though.

Comment: Why didn't you translate "The coat is beige" by "*Le manteau est beige*"? It's not the correct answer but yours is way too far from what you meant in English

Answer (score 26):

The crux of your question is in the sentence:

> From what I understood, Il est means He is. But, Why does it mean It is?

The fact is that in French there is no “it”. The only French grammatical genders are masculine (applied to male people and animals, and to part of inanimate objects, such as *le manteau*, *il*) or feminine (for female people and animals, and the rest of inanimate objects, such as *la chaise*, *elle*).

So, for every French noun you have to learn its gender, masculine or feminine, and agree adjectives and pronouns consequently.

Comment: It is... C'est. The C' (note the apostrophe) is considered a word itself. So:

It was = C'était
It is = C'est
It will = Ça sera
It won't = Ça ne sera

Answer (score 12):

The usual answer to the question : *De quelle couleur est ton manteau ?* is: *Il (mon manteau) est beige.*

Consider it would be the same in English:
What colour **is** your coat? → It **'s** beige.

What you wanted to answer using *a* (3rd person of *avoir*): *Mon manteau a une couleur beige* would not sound idiomatic at all and we never say that in French. And mind the word order.

If you really wanted to mention the word *couleur* in your answer, you could have gone with:  *Mon manteau est de couleur beige*, which is not usual but possible, and slightly clumsy unless in a very specific context.

We do not repeat the word *couleur* in the answer because it is considered as part of the question phrase, and you don't always have the question word or phrase in the answer (it's the same in lots of languages).

*Quel temps fait-il ? →  Il pleut.*
*Quelle est sa nationalité ? → Elle (il)  est français(e).*

But it is not always the case,  you'll probably soon learn (if you haven't yet) *quelle heure est-il ?*, to which a French person would answer: *Il est 3 heures*, keeping the word *heures* in the answer.

Comment: A good way of putting it. Note that a similar wording is used for English questions "How [adjective] is ...?" For example, "How long is it?" It's quite hard for us to wrap our head around the transposition to "De quelle longueur est-ce ?" or "Quelle est sa longueur ?" And so I sometimes do show them the declarative form with this word repeated: "La longueur est ..." or "C'est ____ de longueur." But then the same trick isn't useful here. There are so many exceptions to wrap one's head around.

Comment: To elaborate on one of the examples: French, like English, doesn't allow verbs without subjects. You can say "Mokuyoubi desu" (lit. "Monday is") is Japanese or "Está lloviendo" (lit. "Is raining") is Spanish, but in English you have to say "_It_'s Monday" or "_It_'s raining." There's no genderless form of 'it' in French, so "il" is added: "Il pleut" (It's raining) "Il faut..." (It's necessary to...), "Il vaut mieux que..." (It would be better if...), and so on. In the particular example in the OP, though, "il" is just a normal pronoun referring to the grammatically masucline coat.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I don't feel you answered the question which is really on the gender of words.

Comment: @ApplePie  Gender is an issue (I pointed to it  *Il (mon manteau)* thinking it was sufficient but the use of *avoir* instead of  *être* is an important issue. Explaining this seems just as important. We're here to help within the limits of the site, even if OPs do not see all the issues brought in by their questions.

Comment: @anomaly Spanish doesn’t allow verbs without subjects, either; but unlike French and English, it is perfectly happy with implicit subjects, i.e., subjects being expressed through personal ending alone. English is actually quite okay with that as well, but only in limited contexts where the subject is easily inferrable (i.e., “What’s that man’s name?” — “Can’t tell you. Never saw him before.”).

Comment: `Q: quelle heure est-il ? | A: Il est 3 heures` `keeping the word heures in the answer.` In this case, "heure" in the question represents what is being asked for(the time), and "heure" in the answer represents a unit of measure(hours). hence why the word "heure" is being returned in the answer. Same word, though 2 different "meanings" given the context.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I'd say that's more of a difference between a zero subject and an elided subject. In the latter case, there is a definite subject ("I" in your example), but it's just not stated. In the former case, there's no meaningful subject to the sentence (there is no "it" that's actually raining), and a dummy pronoun gets inserted to satisfy grammatical rules.

Answer (score 5):

You need to understand that in French, like many other languages, objects are *not* automatically neutral ('it') as in English, but female ('she') or male ('he').
You will need to learn for every noun which of the two it is; this is quite an effort for native english speakers.

In your example, *manteau* is male, so it gets the french 'il'.

Comment: Even worse than that: in French (as in many other languages) there is no explicit neutral grammatical gender, so *all* objects are either masculine (*le manteau*, *il*) or feminine (*la chaise*, *elle*).

Comment: There are no neuter nouns in French, only masculine or feminine.

Comment: @DaG Not that languages with neuter distribute it among inanimate objects any more logically than they do masculine and feminine. ;)

Comment: @LukeSawczak I'm not saying that French is logical, but come on, German. "das Mädchen"? Seriously? Being a young lady isn't enough for being feminine?

Comment: The OP already knows that manteau is masculine, though, or they wouldn't have replied "Mon manteau ...".

Comment: @Rightleg In German, _Mädchen_ is a **diminutive**, of which the case is neutral. It's from _Magd_, which is feminine.

Comment: @Rightleg Similarly, in Irish (which has only masculine and feminine like French), _cailín_ ‘girl’ is masculine.

Comment: @MrLister Is "Magd" in everyday use? I never heard of it in nine years of studying German, although I admit I was not the best student...

Comment: @Rightleg I honestly thought that _Mädchen_ was the Verkleinerungswort to _Mädel_, but then Wiktionary told me _Mädel_ was a Verkleinerungswort itself, to _Magd_, which isn't used. Oh well, let's not continue this off-topicness. Case closed, OK? P.S. you probably meant _Weib_.

Answer (score 4):

*Mon manteau **a** beige couleur* is not correct because *a* is a form of *avoir* , not of *être*. French uses the same verb as English in this sentence : *The coat **is** beige* = *Le manteau **est** beige* , or with the pronoun : *Il est beige*. Translating the subject *it* depends of the gender of the noun in French: *le manteau* is masculine => il ; *la chemise* is feminine => elle.

Comment: Bienvenue à French Language Stack Exchange !

Comment: My French is rusty, but I'd say _Mon manteau a couleur beige_ is much less wrong than _Mon manteau est couleur beige_.  A coat *is* not a color, it *has* a color.  Better still, though, _…est **de** couleur beige_.

Comment: *Mon manteau a la couleur beige* would be valid. But nobody says that.

Answer (score 0):

French speaker here. It simply means "It is".

When you wrote "Mon manteau a beige couleur.", it is the same as saying "My coat has color beige". You could say instead "Mon manteau est de couleur beige." which could be translated to "My coat is of beige color".